# How to redirect with rewriterule from all domains and pages?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Let's say I have two domains: mydomain.com and my.domain

And I want to redirect from all pages on mydomain.com including any of its sub-domains to my.domain but keeping the url, eg:

```
text.mydomain.com/goahead/ -> http://my.domain/goahead/
```

I tried this way, but it doesn't seem to work at all:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*?mydomain\.com\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/my\.domain\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Where is the mistake? And what are better practices of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, now I got it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[A-Za-z0-9.]*mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/my\.domain\/$1" [R=301,L]
```